# How can I run an external program automatically using Python script?

Tags: python, subprocess, command-prompt

How can I run an external program automatically using Python script?

I installed a program that can analyze demographics. Let's say the program name is Demograph I am doing the following commands in the Windows command prompt to extract specific people's information.

```
Demograph hobby Baseball FileA > OutputfileA
```

FileA contains people's information. And this command can extract people who like baseball. I can change the baseball to soccer, swimming, etc. This command generates an OutputfileA. As the next step, I am doing the following command to further analyze the OutputfileA.

```
Demograph age 10-15 OutputfileA > OutputfileA2
```

This command can extract people's information whose ages are 10-15 from OutputfileA and then generate the OutputfileA2

However, typing this information on the command prompt every time is a pain.
I want to do this automatically using Python script.
Should I use "subprocess" to run the external program automatically?

Comment: Quite a few more SO Q&A's to peruse searching with variations of `python subprocess execute a program write result to a file site:stackoverflow.com`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, subprocess is really great for it.
Simple use it:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.call([])
```

If you want to parse output, read about STDout pipes and ect in DOC:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use subprocess and this is an example:

```
import subprocess

subprocess.Popen("Demograph hobby Baseball FileA > OutputfileA")

# rest of your code
```